# Expression for expectation using distribution function

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let X be a random variable on some probability space, with distribution function F.

I know that for nonnegative X, we have

$$E(X) = \int_0^\infty (1 - F(t))\,dt$$

But is there a similar result for (not necessarily) nonnegative r.v.'s?

Comment: No, but$X$ can be split up as $X=Y-Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are both nonnegative ones. Here $Y=max(X,0)$ and $Z=max(-X,0)$.

Comment: Yes but then what...? Can the distribution functions for Y and Z be written down easily? If so, then applying the formula above for nonnegative RV's and using linearity of expectation would give a positive answer to my question...

Comment: Okay, make it a 'yes'. And have a look at the answer. That is exactly what you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$X$ can be split up as $X=Y-Z$ where $Y$ and $Z$ are both
nonnegative ones. Here $Y=\max(X,0)$ and $Z=\max(-X,0)$.

For non-negative $x$ you have $P\left\{ Y\leq x\right\} =P\left\{ X\leq x\right\} $
and $P\left\{ Z\leq x\right\} =P\left\{ X\geq-x\right\} $. Then

> $E\left[X\right]=E\left[Y\right]-E\left[Z\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}F_{-}\left(-x\right)dx$

where $F_{-}\left(x\right)=P\left\{ X<x\right\} $.

Here $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(F\left(-x\right)-F_{-}\left(-x\right)\right)dx=0$
so we can also take the nicer looking:

> $E\left[X\right]=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(1-F\left(x\right)\right)dx-\int_{0}^{\infty}F\left(-x\right)dx$

Comment: The last equation is incorrect. For example, if $X$ has density $\frac{1}{2}\exp(-|x|)$ and distribution function $$F(x) = \begin{cases} \frac{1}{2}\exp(x), & x < 0,\\1 - \frac{1}{2}\exp(-x), &x \geq 0,\end{cases}$$ then both integrals on the right side have value $\frac{1}{2}$ and thus $E[X]$ works out to be $1$ instead of $0$ as it should.

Comment: yes indeed, and if F is X is a continuous RV then F and F- are equal - then replacing F- with F in the first equation, and subtracting the two equations for E(X), you would get that for the distribution function F of any continuous RV you have integral(F,0..infinity) = 0 , an obvious contradiction.

Comment: Frank: Then why accept the thing?

Comment: well the first formula was correct as far as I can see ... I accepted before the second was added. Now I have unaccepted

Comment: typo: the + must be a -. Sorry

Comment: @DilipSarwate There is an essential difference between typos and errors. If you meet one then why not repairing it? It is not quite difficult here to discern that the pen of the author slipped. For showing that it is incorrect you do not need an example. The addition of 2 integrals both having a nonnegative integrand will off course be nonnegative, and there are negative expectations also.

Comment: @DilipSarwate This reminds me of the fact that people have principles and that I should respect these principles (wich I do in this case), if there is no decent reason not to. It teaches me a lesson, that I tend to forget easily. Thank you for teaching me.